# Array-index-out-of-bounds exception

Tags: java, android

I am getting an array-out-of-bounds exception error. This is my simple code:

```java
for(int i=0; i<aa.length; i++) {
    String[] event = aa[i].split(" ");
    int mr = 0;
    mr = event[i].length();
    String eventtime = event[mr];
}
```

And this is my error caused:

> Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=5.

The length of my events array is 3. Then the index has to be 3, but it shows me 5. Why?

Comment: You are taking the length of an element of the array, not the array itself. For example, if event[i] has the length 5, but the array has only 3 values, then you will receive the exception. Without knowing what you actually want to achieve, it's hard to say how you can fix it, but what I said above is the reason for the crash.

Comment: I just edited my question I want to get last element of event array

Comment: In this case, see the answer from @Harry Jones

Answer (score 1):

I think you want `mr = event.length` here, although remember that array indices start at 0, so you'll want `mr = event.length - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are taking the length of an element of the array.

Comment: Yes I take the lenght of an element on this "event" array but when I get to last element I getting array bound exception error, this is error line "String eventtime= event[mr];"

Comment: I think this will resolve : `String eventtime= event[mr] - 1;`
If you want to loop through until the end of the array, you have do loop from 0 to length-1 as `indexes` start from 0 and `length` starts from 0(if u have at least one element)

Comment: if you are right error would be Caused by: java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=-1; ?